# ASP.NET MVC crud operation with Entity Framework and AngulaJs and Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, api, entity-framework, crud

I have to build a website in ASP.NET MVC using AngularJs, Entity Framework and Web API.

Please help to do this crud operation in this, please guide me.

To perform crud operations..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried and get help with something specific, if you're too early in the process for that, have a first stop here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 2):

There are good tutorials here:

MVC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

AngularJS and ASP.NET: https://www.codemag.com/article/1605081/Integrating-ASP.NET-MVC-and-Angular-JS